# How to get ASP.Net Core Web Server to listen on non-localhost requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm able to successfully deploy my MVC app onto localhost listening on port `7051`.

Connecting to `https://localhost:7051/` or `https://127.0.0.1:7051/`  works fine. However, connecting to `https://192.168.201.194:7051/` (my LAN IPV4) does not.

How can I configure ASP.Net to listen to non-localhost requests?

There is no information in the docs and all similar questions are very badly outdated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It should be accessible if something in middle is not interfering.

Did you enable World Wide Web Services (HTTP Traffic In) from firewall ?
Try enabling it from Inbound Rules (Control Panel -> Windows Firewall -> Advanced Settings -> Inbound Rules) and you should access localhost from LAN.

Comment: I've already created an inbound rule allowing port 7051 for TCP. Are there any other rules I should create?

Comment: Maybe not, Did you try pinging the IP ?

Comment: telnet 192.168.201.194 7051 fails; telnet can't open a connection

Comment: Please try pinging. Also try netstat -a -o and check if your webapp is listening on all IP address. Also try disabling the firewall(temporarily of course !!) to check if other firewall rule is not interfering

Comment: Pinging works fine and port 7051 is listening only on 127.0.0.1. I found that 192.168.201.194 is listening but on port 139 (I believe used for OS processes however).
Disabling the firewall doesn't fix anything